Compare imported data from CSV with ifthenelse
I'm trying to make a comparison in Latex with data imported from a CSV file.
Unfortunately, the comparison doesn't work (or gives wrong result) when variable is assigned a value from CSV file even though it still prints f when run.
On How test value of a command with `\ifthenelse` and `\equal`? it explains that

\string makes (just) the w a catcode 12 punctuation character so not equal to the letter w

so, I'm assuming that the import converts.
However, I can't find how to avoid/rectify it.
Minimal example:
CSV
1, Luigo, f, Vanilla
2, Wendys, f, Chocolate
3, Luigo, c, Hazelnut

TeX
\documentclass[a4paper,12p]{article}

%CSV name
\newcommand{\CSV}{CSV.csv} 

\usepackage{csvsimple} % read Excel tables
\newcommand{\flavour}{\csvreader[filter equal={\csvcoli}{2}]{\CSV}{}{\csvcoliii}}
\newcommand{\flavourManual}{f}

\begin{document}

\flavour
%\ifthenelse{\equal{\flavour}{f}}{ % gives error
%   Chocolate is great}
%   {A Combination might be better}

\ifthenelse{\equal{\string \flavour}{f}}{ % gives wrong result; tried {\string f} - same outcome
   Chocolate is great}
   {A Combination might be better}

\flavourManual

\ifthenelse{\equal{\flavourManual}{f}}{ 
   Chocolate is great}
   {A Combination might be better}

\end{document}

Error if line 13-15 are not commented out:

Result:

I've tried to change to catcode 12, but failed:
\makeatletter
\def\testa{\csvreader[filter equal={\csvcoli}{2}]{\CSV}{}{\csvcoliii}}
\testa

\edef\testa{\expandafter\strip@prefix\meaning\testa}% Now a 'string' - outputting: “csvreader [filter equal=–“csvcoli ˝–2˝]–“CSV ˝–˝–“csvcoliii ˝
\testa

What do I need to change?

Can you describe what you're trying to do?

@Werner: I'm importing options selected by my colleagues and need to check if they like f or something else (e.g. c). Depending on that selection, I need to run a different output report with \input{F} or \input{C}

Use datatool that provides much more functionality for database loading and extraction/comparison.

% Create a database
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{flavours.csv}
1, Luigo, f, Vanilla
2, Wendys, f, Chocolate
3, Luigo, c, Hazelnut
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{datatool}

% Read database
\DTLloaddb
  [noheader,keys={num,name,flavour,word}]% Options
  {flavours}% db name
  {flavours.csv}% CSV

\begin{document}

% Retrieve a value associated with a reference match
\DTLgetvalueforkey
  {\RetrievedValue}% <cmd>
  {flavour}% <key>
  {flavours}% <db name>
  {num}% <ref key>
  {2}% <ref value>

% Compare retrieved value
\DTLifstringeq*{\RetrievedValue}{f}{True}{False}

\DTLifstringeq*{\RetrievedValue}{c}{True}{False}
  
\end{document}


It works beautifully; I just run into a related problem: if I want to combine \RetrievedValue in OR or AND clauses: how do I do it with \DTLifstringeq*?

@ChrisPeh: Consider using \ifthenelse{\DTLisieq{\RetrievedValue}{f} \or \DTLisieq{\RetrievedValue}{c}}{True}{False} (also \and and \not is available). This does a case insensitive string comparison.
